# decoding avro in go returns map[string]interface {} but cannot range over (type interface {})

Tags: go, avro

Here is the output of the avro decode:

```
native, _, err := codec.NativeFromBinary(b)  //map[string]interface {}
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(native))
fmt.Println(native)

map[string]interface {}
map[com.nasdaq.marketdata.sequencer.applications.datafeed.ultrafeed.ultrafeed30.messaging.SeqOneSidedNBBOShort:map[SoupPartition:0 SoupSequence:49377202 appendages:[] channelIndex: condition: mcLocate:13 msgFlags: msgType:c nbboFlags: price:800 protocol:3 sLocate:17220 side:S size:12 srcNanos:674905424 srcSequence:118438648]]
```

I am trying to access the key sLocate

How?

```
for key, value := range native {
    fmt.Println("Key:", key, "Value:", value)
}

 ./main.go:64:20: cannot range over native (type interface {})
```

So I am rather new to golang and I dont understand.

Comment: Can't reproduce. You can use type conversion like `...range map[string]interface {}(native)` if it's `interface{}` .https://play.golang.org/p/MSpbbfbWcfq

Comment: I dot get? How do I do type conversion? can you place in answer? Thanks.  I would place the whole code but the avro schema is a large file.

Comment: Can you have a look at go playground code in previous comment

Comment: Does it return a `map[string]interface{}`, or an `interface{}` with type `map[string]interface{}`? If it is the latter, you need a type assertion: `for key, value := range native.(map[string]interface{}) {/*...*/}`